# How to fix arranging objects by date in the Class Based Views in Django

Tags: python, django

This is a beginner's question I am trying to arrange orders by ordered date but it is not working I tried 2 things to add order in the CBV directly and in a get_queryset but both are not working.

I am trying to learn how to do it correctly, they are currently ordered from old to new and I am trying to arrange them from new dates to old.

Here is the model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

here are the views.py

```
class OrderList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "user_orders.html"
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    ordering = ['-ordered_date']

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True)
            context = {
                'orders': order,
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'user_orders.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have any orders")
            return redirect("/")
    def get_queryset(self):
         return Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you added any Order items with date in admin panel or mention `auto_now_add = True` in datetimefield and migrate again

Comment: can you also show your HTML template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add order_by here

```
order = Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')
```